# CSS div with larger bottom line as a whole

Tags: html, css

Any idea how to do this

[image]
in CSS?

What I want is them to be together as a whole. Like a div with a hover on it, everytime the user passes the mouse over it, both the line and the text's background will change color. I've tried different approaches but can't seem to get this as a whole. What I have right now is:

http://jsfiddle.net/RmNJL/

**HTML**

```
<div class="example">
    <span>2014</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.example {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.example span {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
}
.example:hover { border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6); }
.example span:hover { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); }
```

I want them to be together as a single `div`/unit. So it only changes to the `hover` color if the user passes the mouse in front of the line or the text. Also, hovering the line would also hover the text background at the same time.

I know it may sound confusing but it's not easy to explain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
    .example {
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    .example span {
        display: inline-block;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
        padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    }
    .example:hover { border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6); }
    .example:hover span { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); }
```

Comment: That's awesome! Never thought it would be that simple. Though if you pass the mouse over the empty space (the .example) it still considers you're passing in front of either the line or the text. Any way to avoid tis?

Comment: That's real quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7JACz/ 

It has one disadvantage though, there is fixed margin to position year in the center of bottom bar.

Comment: I see... it can't be that way though =( perhaps another way?

Comment: Well, you can do sth like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7JACz/1/ It uses CSS3 property transform: translateX. So you don't have to worry about positioning in the middle of .example container.